# Help with GAP code on finding generators of spherical systems.

Tags: group-theory, gap

I am looking at a specific group $G$ and trying to find an index 2 subgroup with generators of length 3, such that the generators form a spherical system.  Here, an $r$-tuple $[g_1,\ldots,g_r]$ of elements of $G$ is called a *spherical system of generators* if $g_1,\ldots,g_r$ generate $G$ and we additionally have $g_1\cdots g_r=1$.

So far, I have written code for the group with a maximal two quotient of class 3.  I'd be interested to change the class at a later point and see the effect if any.

$\left\langle\ x_{0},...,x_{20}\mid x_{i}x_{i+7}x_{i+14}, x_{i}x_{i+14}x_{i+7}, x_{i}x_{i+3}x_{i+15}\:(i\in\mathbb{Z}_{21})\right\rangle$

```
f:=FreeGroup(List([1..21],i->Concatenation("x_",String(i mod 21))));;
gens:=GeneratorsOfGroup(f);;
m:=function(a,b) return ((a-1) mod b)+1; end;;
LIST1 :=List([1..21],i->Product(gens{List([i,i+7,i+14],j->m(j,21))}));;
LIST2 :=List([1..21],i->Product(gens{List([i,i+14,i+7],j->m(j,21))}));;
LIST3 :=List([1..21],i->Product(gens{List([i,i+3,i+15],j->m(j,21))}));;
r := Concatenation([ LIST1, LIST2, LIST3 ]);;
g:=f/r;;
epi:=EpimorphismPGroup(g,2,3);;
G:=Image(epi); 
Size(G); 
p:=PresentationFpGroup(g); 
SimplifyPresentation(p); 
TzPrintPresentation(p);
```

Now to find a subgroup H with index 2, I have used

```
H:=LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup( g,2);
```

And so I now need to find the generators and relators of these.  So I have,

```
GeneratorsOfGroup(H[ i ]);   
h:=SimplifiedFpGroup(Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(H[i]))); 
RelatorsOfGroup(h);
```

I am struggling with the need to go through all H[i] (I think there are 25 in this case).  What is also not apparent is whether they form a spherical system of generators.  In particular, I cannot see any subgroups that have generators of length 3.

Has anybody got any tips on how to possibly look for this or smarten up the code?

Thanks

Comment: What is a spherical system.  Also you make no use of the presentation you simplified.

Comment: Let G be a finite group and r an integer with r>=2.  An r-tuple of T+[g_1,...,g_r] of elements of G is called a spherical system of generators, if g_1,...,g_r generate G and we additionally have g_1,...,g_r=1.

Comment: Note that thers is no guarantee that the generators you get for teh subgroup (which are Schreier generators) form a minimal set. You might want to pick a few subgroup elements (e.g. as pre-images of generators in quotients) and try whether they still generate a subgroup of same index.

Comment: Thanks, @ahulpke.  I used AbelianInvariants and realised that this was not possible in the end.